# How hard is a Deva boss fight for two level 10 characters?

Tags: dnd-5e, encounter-design, one-shot

I'm planning a one shot for two level 10 characters and I'd like a challenging boss fight for the end of it. The plan at the moment is that they will fight a corrupted Deva in the tomb of a Beholder God. The Deva will take the stats of the [Deva](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/deva) from the *Monster Manual*, and the partially revived Beholder god will have a 1/4 chance of firing a random eye ray (again stats taken from [Beholder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/beholder) from the *Monster Manual*) at one of the characters.

I've never run a boss fight like this before and have no experience with characters of level 10 or above (I've been DMing for a few years but usually for lower-level parties up to level 7-8). Any advice on this would be great, as I'd hate to have the fight be too easy or unreasonably difficult.

The characters are:

- level 10 Dwarf Cleric
- level 10 Gold Dragonborn Paladin

Comment: @HenryPowell Thank you for clarifying! I have edited in the dnd-5e tag to indicate the game you are playing. Be sure to take the [tour] as an introduction to how the site works and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Do you know what prepared spells your party is going to be going into the fight with?

Comment: Unfortunately not. V2Blast's answer below has answered the question but thanks for you comment!

Comment: @HenryPowell V2Blast only edited, I answered it.

Comment: @NeutralVax Ah, well then thanks to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will end up mostly likely deadly.

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* has a chart for XP chart for character by level.

At level 10, the XP thresholds for an individual character are

- Easy: 600
- Medium: 1,200
- Hard: 1,900
- Deadly: 2,800

The Deva has  Challenge Rating of 10 (5,900 XP).

The cleric and paladin will have a a combined XP threshold of 5,600 for a deadly encounter. The Deva alone is above that threshold. Even without the beholder, the Deva alone is likely to wipe the floor with them.

A simple solution would be to add an NPC of similar or slightly lower level than the characters.

Comment: This is very useful, thanks a lot. I suspected that this would be case so I will change the NPC to something easier. Marked as answered.

Comment: The Deva would actually have an expected challenge level equivalent to 8550 XP according to the *Dungeon Master's Guide*. This is because of the Party Size rules which say: "If the party contains fewer than three characters, apply the next highest multiplier on the Encounter Multipliers table. For example, apply a multiplier of 1.5 when the characters fight a single monster"

Comment: @HenryPowell Do note my above comment; two party members can handle *less* than half of four (which is why the rules about Party Size are present in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*)

Comment: @DavidCoffron Didn't see that. I also wasn't factoring the beholder.

Comment: @DavidCoffron Duely noted, many thanks.